# Docker can't find file next to python file

Tags: python, docker, import, path

I'm trying to read a json file from Python within a docker container. It works locally, but does not work when it runs on docker, I get the error:

```
  File "//application/scheduler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import App
  File "/application/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fixtures import RaceCard
  File "/application/fixtures.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dataset_generator.firebase.config import DB
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dataset_generator/firebase/config.py", line 26, in <module>
    cred = credentials.Certificate(json_path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 83, in __init__
    with open(cert) as json_file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dataset_generator/firebase/oddsgenie-firebase.json'
```

```
❯ ~/Desktop/comp702/dataset_generator/firebase >ls
config.py
export.csv
export.json
exports.py
__init__.py
oddsgenie-firebase.json
__pycache__
reduced_export.csv
reduced_export.json
```

Code I'm using to import the file from `Desktop/comp702/dataset_generator/firebase/exports.py`

```
class Export():
    def __init__(self, init=False):
        #config
        self.script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.json_path = os.path.join(self.script_directory, 'oddsgenie-firebase.json')
        self.cred = credentials.Certificate(self.json_path)
        if init:
            self.app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(self.cred)
            self.db = firestore.client()
```

What do I need to change to be able to read this file from within the Docker container? The Dockerfile is located within the `comp702` directory.

Dockerfile contents below:

```
FROM python:3.11
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install .
CMD ["python3", "application/scheduler.py"]
```

Comment: You're reading from the wrong path. If the file is present on the host on path
~/Desktop/comp702/dataset_generator/firebase. Try mounting the directory to the container and read from there

Comment: @aksh02 how would I go about mounting the directory onto the container? I would've thought that it would be accessible after the line `COPY . .`

Comment: If you copied the directory, you can check the file location by opening a shell to container and running find command.